# Unable to resolve leap seconds miscalculation on calendar

Tags: php, date, mktime

I have a calendar that is showing me the wrong days of the date for the day of the week. More specifically, they are one day behind the actual date.

I've done a bunch of research and used the following SO question ([php date('d') calculates same output for two consecutive days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041380/php-dated-calculates-same-output-for-two-consecutive-days)) but I can't get it to work on my script.

It's currently displaying the 26th of october twice, from there on the dates go wrong.

```
$firstday = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);
$day = date('Y-m-d',$firstday);
$fday = strtotime($day." last Sunday ",$firstday);
$currday_timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),date('d'),date('Y'));

for($i=0;$i<7;$i++) {
            $firstweek[$i]['id'] = date("Y-m-d",$fday+(86400 * $i));
            $firstweek[$i]['val'] = date("d",$fday+(86400 * $i));
            if($currday_timestamp > $fday+(86400 * $i)) {
                $firstweek[$i]['flag'] = 1;    
            }
            $secondweek[$i]['id'] = date("Y-m-d",$fday+(86400 * ($i+7)));
            $secondweek[$i]['val'] = date("d",$fday+(86400 * ($i+7)));
            if($currday_timestamp > $fday+(86400 * ($i+7))) {
                $secondweek[$i]['flag'] = 1;    
            }
            $thirdweek[$i]['id'] = date("Y-m-d",$fday+(86400 * ($i+14)));
            $thirdweek[$i]['val'] = date("d",$fday+(86400 * ($i+14)));
            if($currday_timestamp > $fday+(86400 * ($i+14))) {
                $thirdweek[$i]['flag'] = 1;    
            }
            $fourthweek[$i]['id'] = date("Y-m-d",$fday+(86400 * ($i+21)));
            $fourthweek[$i]['val'] = date("d",$fday+(86400 * ($i+21)));
            if($currday_timestamp > $fday+(86400 * ($i+21))) {
                $fourthweek[$i]['flag'] = 1;    
            }
            $fifthweek[$i]['id'] = date("Y-m-d",$fday+(86400 * ($i+28)));
            $fifthweek[$i]['val'] = date("d",$fday+(86400 * ($i+28)));
            if($currday_timestamp > $fday+(86400 * ($i+28))) {
                $fifthweek[$i]['flag'] = 1;    
            }
            $sixthweek[$i]['id'] = date("Y-m-d",$fday+(86400 * ($i+35)));
            $sixthweek[$i]['val'] = date("d",$fday+(86400 * ($i+35)));
            if($currday_timestamp > $fday+(86400 * ($i+35))) {
                $sixthweek[$i]['flag'] = 1;    
            }
        }
```

How would I go about tackling this leap seconds problem? Is there a value I need to add to the seconds?

Comment: This is the wrong way to do date math. When you work with literal seconds you run into many issues, this being one them, daylight savings being another. Use DateTime() and DateInterval() to do date math in PHP.

Comment: I'll rework the entire function in the future but I've used markt answer for now as a quick solution. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this is a to do with the change from daylight saving time to standard time.

Simplest way is to add a couple of hours to your base time:

```
$time_offset = 2 * 60 * 60; // 2 hours
$firstday = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year) + $time_offset;
$day = date('Y-m-d',$firstday);
$fday = strtotime($day." last Sunday ",$firstday) + $time_offset;
$currday_timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),date('d'),date('Y')) + $time_offset;
```

Comment: No, the simplest way is to not do math by adding seconds.

Comment: This fixed it for me as a quick fix. I don't know if there are any drawbacks tied to this solution but I appreciate the quick help. I'll rebuild the function following to John's advice in the future.